# su cannot execute bin/bash/****

Tags: sudo, root, su

I installed Kali Linux on a VM machine and I cannot change my user to root from the terminal using `su`. The command `sudo` works fine but when I try to `su`, it says "cannot execute bin/bash/****(my user name) not a directory".

Comment: Check to see what the entry in `/etc/passwd` looks like for the user you're trying to su to.

Comment: Does `su -` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your error message, it looks like the `login shell` for the root user is not set properly in the `/etc/passwd` file.

```
$ grep root /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Mostly in your system it might be as

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash/****
```

Where `****` is your username.

Open `/etc/passwd` file and correct the login shell.

Comment: I logged in as root and deleted my user name from the end of bin/bash but now it just says cannot execute /bin/bash not a directory.

Comment: paste the output of `grep root /etc/passwd` command, lets see if there is some thing missing

Comment: Did you perhaps leave the trailing slash at the end of `/bin/bash`?

Comment: wurtel was right i left the slash on and now 'su' works.

Comment: what if I can't edit `/etc/passwd` because I can't login as root?

Comment: in my case someone forgot the leading slash... `root:x:0:0:root:/root:bin/bash`  argh!